# Change option menu's items on item selection

Tags: android, refresh, optionmenu

I'm trying to change the option menu after an item on the menu is selected. 
This is what I tried:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if(refresh) {

        menu.clear();
        menu.add(0, Menu.FIRST, 0, "Changed item");

    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.refresh)
    {
        refresh = true;
        closeOptionsMenu();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But I get:

```
W/InputManagerService(192): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of:     com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4147c778
```

and the code is not working..
Any idea?

Comment: Which line does the LogCat show throwing the exception?

Comment: It's not an exception, it's a warning from the InputManagerService, so i don't know which operation is responsible for that..

Comment: So it is. Does your code work? Do you just want to avoid the warning?

Comment: No my code it's not working (going to edit the question :D), the menu will close and not reopen, only if i reclick on the menu button i see the new value

Comment: Ok, but it looks like the change happens. Sadly this is the way the options menu works, though you can use a Runnable to automatically reopen it. Would you like an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the menu will close and not reopen, only if i reclick on the menu button i see the new value

I don't know of anyway to keep the options menu open after an item has been selected, however you can reopen it automatically with a Handler and Runnable.

Create a couple new field variables:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable reopenMenu = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
};
```

And inside `onOptionsItemSelected()` use:

```
if(item.getItemId() == R.id.refresh)
{
    refresh = true;
    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // This is only necessary for changing an ActionBar
    handler.postDelayed(reopenMenu, 100);
}
```

(Notice I removed the calls to close and open the menu.)
Lastly you should set `refresh = false;` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` since you only need to make the change once.

Comment: Handler + Runnable where the key, now it's perfectly working, thank you Sam.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to have the second button already on the menu but visibility set to GONE, and then make it visible when you need.

```
MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menuItem);

MenuItem.setVisible(false);
```